# Batch Analysis on HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hdfs, batch-processing

I generally work with real-time analysis using Spark Structured Streaming, Kafka, HBase etc. I didn't develop any batch analysis job/system. I want to learn batch analysis design and develop. For this I try to understand `lambda architecture` but I don't know somethings.

---

Let's go over the assumptions.

I'm getting clickstream data in real time. All data sent to the Kafka to ingest.

**Speed Layer:** We can analyze sessions from the clickstream data in real-time using Spark Streaming / Flink etc. Then we can send analyzed results to the HBase, Cassandra etc. This is the speed layer of the `lambda architecture.` I generally know this layer(I also work in this layer).

---

**Batch Layer:** We can send data from Kafka to the HDFS using Apache Nifi, Kafka Connect etc. First question in here;

**Question1:** How can I send data to the HDFS? HDFS has `write once read many` concept. Should I send data as batch format from Kafka to the HDFS(e.g. every 5 or 10 minutes)? How should the file format be? JSON, Parquet, Text, CSV etc?

After send data to the HDFS, assume that analyze it using Hive or Spark SQL. I configured job for this at every 30 minutes. This job generally is the same with the streaming analyze. But it runs every 30 minutes, and analyzes user sessions(user behaviour).

**Question2:** How can I get only new data from HDFS(received data after previous batch)?

**Question3:** Assume that I want to access session analyze results from previous batch in the current batch analyze, how can I merge current batch analyze and previously session analyze result?

**Question4:** Should I write data to the HDFS as partition format? For example, each clickstream data have timestamp. Thus, should I write it by year,day,hour,minute etc?

Thank you so much for now!

Answer (score 2):

,

Some of these answers are subjective. YOu can think of what suits your needs best. These are just my observations or techniques i have used in the past

Question1: How can I send data to the HDFS? HDFS has write once read many concept. Should I send data as batch format from Kafka to the HDFS(e.g. every 5 or 10 minutes)? How should the file format be? JSON, Parquet, Text, CSV etc?

Depending on the source you use , you can choose to stream data into HDFS or Hive or even layers like HBase (depending on use cases where you may share a store for online + offline). I have large kafka pipelines that i stream data into Hive (ORC) , i have used Storm in the past , but the layer is upto you to choose. You can choose any columnar format that may suit your processing need (ORC , Parquet , Avro are popular choices)

After send data to the HDFS, assume that analyze it using Hive or Spark SQL. I configured job for this at every 30 minutes. This job generally is the same with the streaming analyze. But it runs every 30 minutes, and analyzes user sessions(user behaviour).

Again , depending on how you have stored , you can use HiveQL or Spark SQL to analyze. I personally prefer spark as i find programmatic operators handy than SQL like operators on HiveQL. The support set of operators is large as well.

Question2: How can I get only new data from HDFS(received data after previous batch)?

This problem is solved if you stream data. If you read is a batch as well , you may want to maintain some offset management (e.g. in case of Kafka or Azure Event Hub etc.) prefereably on a system that is fail safe or has the redundancy (e.g. Zookeeper). You can take a cue from how typical data warehousing techniques solve the problem by having a time dimension on the data ingestion and then using a one row - one column table that says till what timestamp did you process. I prefer having a simple epoch on the largest time you processed in the run. In the next run use a SQL operator where you can say where IngestionTS >  and this will retrieve the delta

Question3: Assume that I want to access session analyze results from previous batch in the current batch analyze, how can I merge current batch analyze and previously session analyze result?

You have to have a data strategy here. Do you have time bound data that may come delayed ? . I will tell you a practical scenario , we have transactions that we analyze that may come in 2 days late!. Based on rules we sometimes ignore them , sometimes we recalculate the aggregations and save them. One way if you have to recalculate is to have a time version record. Depending on when the batch ran , we used to have a sliding window to accomodate 2 days worth of data (computationally expensive , cant help) or even have special tables for these delayed data records & recalculate the data , then add a version to the computed record. This can be a simple epoch time when the batch ran. You can then choose the aggregation which has the largest "version"

Question4: Should I write data to the HDFS as partition format? For example, each clickstream data have timestamp. Thus, should I write it by year,day,hour,minute etc?

Yes you should. How do you plan to segment the data , you can choose a partitioning strategy based on that. We use transaction types in some cases , date time in some cases. Invariably they are guided by how you will select and operate on the data. For example , you can have a strategy to calculate aggregates by day and then drop that partition of raw data.

As you see my answers above are just subjective , plain based on use cases i have done. there are lot of variations on these that you can apply to your data!. Happy data engineering

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! Generally I know these concepts. But I didn't understand "spark/hive job runs every 30 minutes". Yeah it runs every 30 minutes, but how can you get only last 30 minutes data? For this, Hive is generally used. But how is your sql query? THERE IS NO ANY EXAMPLE FOR THIS. Also, all people says "we are sending clickstream data to the HDFS for batch processing.". Yeah you are sending it. But clickstream is by nature timestamp data. For this HBase is generally better for me. Right? Also you can query it with Hive. Parquet format also may be good for this.

Comment: Maybe, we can analyze streaming data as batch format(e.g. every 30 minutes again) with apache spark sql job with kafka(it is batch job, not streaming job). Then we can write analyzed results to the HDFS as specified format. Is this solution optional if we don't want to store raw data?

Comment: Generally if your analysis are time-series , timeseries databases serve you well. There are a few choices for that , may be openTSDB or druid and the likes of that. HBase is great for Consistency & Keyed query, but when it comes to pure time data you will need to model well.As for the hive part , if you have a time based data , you can dump it in ORC or Parquet for example into Hive , have may be a timestamped column (ingestion time may be) and then every hour you just do HQL that says ingestiontime>=now-30*60*1000 or something like that. Sorry if it is long , Dont know if i am making sense !